# Como puedo quitar las funciones de "Code Spell Checker" del click derecho VISUAL STUDIO CODE

Tags: vscode

Como puedo QUITAR LAS FUNCIONES Code Spell Checker CUANDO DOY CLICK DERECHO EN VISUAL STUDIO CODE

he estado intentando buscar la manera de quitar estas funciones del click derecho pero no he hallado la manera de hacerlo sin desinstalar la extensión ya que lo requiero pero me molesta al tenerlo ahí, ya que lo normal lo termino usando cuando le doy click al foquito (las funciones rápidas).

Versión de VSCode: 1.63.2

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Será ésto? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=swyphcosmo.spellchecker

Comment: no merefiero a [Code Spell Checker](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=streetsidesoftware.code-spell-checker) es  otra extension

Answer (score 0):

El menú contextual no es modificable por el usuario de VSCode, hasta donde yo sé (que no es taaanto). Habría que hacerle una solicitud al que mantiene la extensión para que le añada [Menu Contribution points](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.menus) a la extensión, con eso podría configurarse la visibilidad de las mismas.

Answer (score 0):

Para desactivar el corrector ortográfico cSpell en VS Code, puede seguir los siguientes pasos:

1. Abra la paleta de comandos presionando `Ctrl + Shift + P` en Windows/Linux o `Cmd + Shift + P` en Mac.
2. Escriba "Preferences: Open User Settings" y selecciónelo.
3. En la barra de búsqueda de la configuración, escriba "cSpell.enabled".
4. Desmarque la casilla de verificación junto a "cSpell: Enabled" para desactivar el corrector ortográfico.
5. Guarde los cambios en la configuración.